# What is "group of graph"?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, geometric-group-theory

I'm reading some old [article](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/44326/10_2005_Article_BF01844162.pdf;jsessionid=8D6EC8665CCE89054F42179EBBF31295?sequence=1) and I have one small question: what in general is the group of a graph? By the article, definition should be in Harary's *Graph Theory*, but unfortunately I don't have any access to that book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group of $G$ just means the automorphism group of $G$, i.e. the collection of all isomorphisms of $G$ with itself, the group operation being composition.

Here is the relevant section from Harary's *Graph Theory*:

> [image]